# Using requests in a loop provides different HTML than using it outside of the loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm attempting to use Python to scrape historic exchange rates from a website.
If I scrape the site manually:

```
url = "https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=2018-07-12"
page = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("tbody")
```

The result is the correct HTML I'm looking for.

However, if I use the same block inside this loop:

```
for d in date_generated:
    date = str(d).replace("00:00:00", "")
    url = "https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=" + date
    page = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find("tbody")

    for i,x in zip(table.find_all("a"), table.find_all("td", class_="")):
        time.sleep(3)
        request += 1
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print(i.text.strip(), x.text.strip())
```

I don't get the correct HTML content. The generated URL's work, and I get a 200 status_code but a NoneType object is returned at the second loop when it attempts to use the table, indicating that it never got the HTML I wanted in the first place (But I do get it if I run it out of the loop).

For those asking, here's how the dates are generated.

```
   start_time = time.time()
   start = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-07-07", "%Y-%m-%d")
   end = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-07-12", "%Y-%m-%d")
   date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=p) for p in range(0, (end- 
   start).days)]
```

Comment: Websites will limit the number of requests. In order to solve this, you need to specify request headers.

Comment: I don't know how many dates there are in `dates_generated` but you can try to limit your requests by placing a `time.sleep(1)` in the loop and see how it does then

Comment: What do you mean a "NoneType object is returned"? Returned from where? Which line? p.s. Feel free to copy and paste the code from your first snippet into your last one. This will take less than it took to type the comment and be more clear.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Updated the post, thanks for the formatting help. Anyways, the NoneObject is returned when the script attempts to use it in the second for loop but there is no actual object because the script in the first loop never found one, unlike when I run it manually.

Comment: @EcoEffect0 thanks for the additional details. Can you please be more specific? What is the exact error and which line causes it?  Which variable has the value `None`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The variable "table", this is the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'. The error is caused by the second for loop, "for x,i..."

Comment: @EcoEffect0 What is the value of `date` on the iteration when the error occurs? You should save `page` to a file and load the HTML in your browser, or otherwise inspect it manually.

Comment: could you please post the value of `dates_generated`?

Comment: @Fozoro Updated the post for you to see.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did as you suggested, and I located the problematic HTML. Where the table is usually located was instead replaced by:" <div class="norates">
Rates not available on requested date. Please try another date." Which is weird because I get a valid URL that I can go and manually get the HTML from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*for the sake of this answer lets say that the value of `d` is equal to `2018-07-07 00:00:00`*.

Nonetheless, when you run:

```
date = str(d).replace("00:00:00", "")
```

you forget the space between `2018-07-07` and `00:00:00`.

So you should replace this line with:

```
date = str(d).replace(" 00:00:00", "")
```

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Haha, I cannot believe it. This worked! I actually wrote another version of this script using Selenium to simulate the web-browser but it was far too slow. The fact it was the space is absolutely maddening. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Websites will limit the number of requests. In order to solve this, you need to specify request headers. Try this:

```
for d in date_generated:
    date = str(d).replace("00:00:00", "")
    url = "https://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=" + date
    head = {'user-agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)'
                              'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                              'Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36'),
                              'referer': None}
    head['referer'] = url

    page = requests.get(url, timeout=5, headers=head)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. Still got a NoneType object returned. Don't believe the issue has to do with the number of requests either. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: @EcoEffect0 then I don't believe this is a http request issue since I ran this code and it works correctly. Please include date_generated in your question

Answer (score -1):

You might be overloading the website, sending too many requests as once and being put on a timeout. Try placing a `time.sleep(1)` in the loop, as @hootnot suggested. If (1) isn't enough, try a longer timeout.